# Uni-directional Transformer VS Bi-directional BERT

Tags: nlp, transformer-model, pre-trained-model, bert-language-model

I just finished reading the [Transformer](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7181-attention-is-all-you-need.pdf) paper and [BERT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805) paper. But couldn't figure out why Transformer is uni-directional and BERT is bi-directional as mentioned in BERT paper. As they don't use recurrent networks, it's not so straightforward to interpret the directions. Can anyone give some clue? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To clarify, the original Transformer model from Vaswani et al. is an encoder-decoder architecture. Therefore the statement "Transformer is uni-directional" is misleading.

In fact, the transformer *encoder* is bi-directional, which means that the self-attention can attend to tokens both on the left and right. In contrast, the *decoder* is uni-directional, since while generating text one token at a time, you cannot allow the decoder to attend to the right of the current token. The transformer decoder constrains the self-attention by masking the tokens to the right.

BERT uses the transformer encoder architecture and can therefore attend both to the left and right, resulting in "bi-directionality".

From the BERT paper itself:

> We note that in the literature the bidirectional Transformer is often referred to as a “Transformer encoder” while the left-context-only version is referred to as a “Transformer decoder” since it can be used for text generation.

Recommended reading: [this article](https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-bert/).

Comment: Great interpretation! I also thought the Transformer encoder was bi-directional by attending both left and right tokens. Here the uni-directional and bi-directional are a bit different from the concepts in RNN. Your response makes it very clear.

Comment: In that sense, is the decoder bidirectional as well? Basically you feed the already predicted words into the decoder, and these words can attend in both directions.